# care-o-bot simulator crashing gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, care-o-bot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I'm trying to run the care-o-bot simulation, the gazebo simulator briefly appears, then crashes with the error below.  I'm running ubuntu 10.4 with electric.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Paul.

```
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_factory.so: libgazebo_ros_factory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:326 : Exception: Failed to load the World
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_factory.so: libgazebo_ros_factory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Error Loading Gazebo
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:326 : Exception: Failed to load the World
/tmp/buildd/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo-1.4.3/debian/ros-electric-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/controllers/ControllerFactory.cc:99 : Exception: Failed to load libgazebo_ros_factory.so: libgazebo_ros_factory.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 12992, exit code -11].
log files: /home/myname/.ros/log/556b4bbc-df3e-11e0-ac48-0026c7674548/gazebo-2*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11216/care-o-bot-simulator-crashing-gazebo/) by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 271 on 2011-09-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Paul, this is the same issue for `libgazebo_ros_factory.so` reported [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2166/shadow-simulator-depends-on-non-existing).

If you are doing:

```
export ROBOT=cob3-1
export ROBOT_ENV=ipa-kitchen
roslaunch cob_bringup sim.launch
```

effectively launching gazebo with `cob_gazebo_worlds/common/worlds/empty.world`.

The released electric debs for cob_gazebo_worlds under cob_simulation stack contains references to the `libgazebo_ros_factory.so` plugins at the time of this post.  So if you have done

```
sudo apt-get install ros-electric-cob-*
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

To setup your ros environment, then this error applies.  The deprecated plugins have indeed been removed from the world files in the development trunk, the fix will probably propagate out into the debs soon.  I would check the cob wiki or ping the stack maintainer to double check the release schedule.  Or in the meantime, you can run from an overlay of cob_simulation stack.

Also, I've changed gazebo's behavior such that it does not throw and exit if a controller plugin library is missing.  This change is released with [simulator_gazebo 1.4.5](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/ChangeList/1.4).

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-15**:
Thanks John.  I'll try this fix.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2011-09-15**:
@PaulOnc, I updated my answer above, is it possible you are running from the debian packages?  (I.e. if "rospack find cob_simulation" points to "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/cob_simulation").

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-14**:
John - regarding the git repository:  would I not have the most current repository I need given how recently I installed cob?  Also, I installed electric from scratch this evening.  What other repository could be out of date?   Thanks.  -Paul.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-14**:
Hi John.  I installed the cob stack this evening.  When I look at cob_simulation/cob_gazebo_worlds/common/worlds, the .world files there all have libgazebo_ros_factor in them.  However, when I removed it (as suggested in your link above) from the ipa-kitchen.world, I get the same error results.  I'm not sure if that's the correct .world file however.

**Comment by [Paul0nc](https://answers.ros.org/users/1067/paul0nc/) on 2011-09-14**:
Thanks Hsu.  I'll give the reported solution a try.  To launch my simulation, I'm going through the sequence found at http://www.care-o-bot-research.org/software/tutorials/move-the-robot-in-simulation.  The command that finally elicits the error is: roslaunch cob_bringup sim.launch

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, the fix is in the new release which ich now available in the debian sources of electric, too.

---

Originally posted by [weisshardt](https://answers.ros.org/users/1163/weisshardt/) with karma: 106 on 2011-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1